# Recursive lambda calculus function

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lambda-calculus, y-combinator

I would like to create a lambda calculus function P such that `(P x y z)` gives `((x y)(x P)(P z))`. I have tried using variants of the Y-combinator/Turing combinator, i.e. functions of the form `λg.(g g)`, since I need to reproduce the function itself, but I can't see any way forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want to solve "β-equation" `P x y z = (x y) (x P) (P z)`.
There is a general method of solving equations of the form `M = ... M ...`.
You just wrap the right-hand side in a lambda, forming a term `L`, where all occurrences of `M` are replaced by `m`:

```
L = λm. ... m ...
```

Then using a fixed-point combinator you get your solution. Let me illustrate it on your example.

```
L = λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z)),
    where λxyz. is a shorthand for λx. λy. λz.
```

Then, `P = Y L`, unfolding `Y` and `L` we get:

```
P = (λf. (λg. f (g g)) (λg. f (g g))) (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z)))
  ->β
(λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g))
// the previous line is our "unfolded" P
```

Let's check if `P` does what we want:

```
P x y z
    =   // unfolding definition of P
(λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) x y z
    ->β
((λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) ((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)))) x y z
    ->β
(λxyz. (x y) (x ((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)))) (((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g))) z)) x y z
    ->β
(x y) (x ((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)))) (((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g))) z)
    =   // folding 1st occurrence of P
(x y) (x P) (((λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g)) (λg. (λp. (λxyz. (x y) (x p) (p z))) (g g))) z)
    =   // folding 2nd occurrence of P
(x y) (x P) (P z)
```

Q.E.D.

Answer (score 2):

[U-combinator](http://matt.might.net/articles/js-church/) should help you create a self-referential lambda abstraction.

Here is Ω, the smallest non-terminating program that exhibits the U-combinator nicely.

```
((λf. (f f))
 (λf. (f f)))
```

If you can  give it a name

```
Ω := λf.(f f)
```

Here's what it might look like with your abstraction

```
((λP. (P P x y z))
 (λP. λx. λy. λz. ((x y) (x P) (P z))))
```

Or using Ω

```
λx. λy. λz. Ω (λP. λx. λy. λz. ((x y) (x P) (P z))) x y z
```